# Given the following file structure, how can you run a basic protractor test?

Tags: node.js, selenium, jasmine, webdriver, protractor

I have been trying to follow a tutorial given [HERE](http://www.protractortest.org/#/). However, when I try to start the protractor test given, no tests seem to run at all. My webdriver-manager seems to run perfectly however. Basically nothing happens.

I have tried the following:

```
node protractor conf.js
node node_modules/protractor conf.js
node node_modules/protractor node_modules/protractor/conf.js
node node_modules/protractor node_modules/protractor/tests/conf.js
```

None of these work, and the first one throws an error. I've tried putting copies of the files in multiple directories, but none of those seem to work either. I'm no exactly sure what the issue is, but this is how much files are setup.

```
ui_directory/ <-- This is the overall directory for my web projects
ui_directory/conf.js
ui_directory/todo-spec.js
ui_directory/node_modules/ 
ui_directory/node_modules/protractor/
ui_directory/node_modules/protractor/conf.js
ui_directory/node_modules/protractor/todo-spec.js
ui_directory/node_modules.protractor/tests/
ui_directory/node_modules.protractor/tests/conf.js
ui_directory/node_modules.protractor/tests/todo-spec.js
```

What exactly is the proper command to run the tests from the tutorial? All todo-spec.js and conf.js files are the same.

My conf.js file contains the following:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

Comment: All but the first one display absolutely nothing. The first one basically says that it couldn't find my conf.js file

Comment: So basically if I run: $ node protractor dir/conf.js, it returns a blank line

Comment: I just tried to run: node protractor --version, and the same thing happened. So maybe it's not related to protractor. And yes I have. protractor conf.js gives "-bash: protractor: command not found"

Comment: I don't know why, but this solved it: "./node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js"

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to run basic protractor Test.

1. Create a Folder, Say example in Desktop (Folder name is protractor)
2. Create a config and Spec file with `.js` extension
3. Make sure both the files are in Same Location / Folder
4. Open Command Prompt, And Navigate to project Folder (protractor)
5. Once navigated to project folder, Type as in bracket:

   `[protractor config.js]` // This will execute protractor Test
6. Example of Basic Protractor Config File is given as

   ```
   exports.config = {

   //The address of a running selenium server.

   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

   //Here we specify the name of the specs files.

    framework: 'jasmine',

    specs: ['Protractor_spec.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {

    showColors: true,

    includeStackTrace: true,

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1440000

    },

   }
   ```